# How to align section titles without numbers left to section titles with numbers in TOC with a global way?

Tags: table-of-contents, titletoc, section-titles

Firt a MWE is as follows.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{tocloft}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Chapter title}
\section{Section title with numbers}

\phantomsection
\section*{Section title without numbers}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Section title without numbers}

\end{document}
```

The compiled result is as follows, and as you see, the section title without the number isn't aligned left to the section title with the number in the first picture.

[image]

Replacing the codes

```
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Section title without numbers}
```

by

```
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\hspace{2.3em}Section title without numbers}
```

(2.3em is the value of `\cftsecnumwidth` in the `tocloft` package), the compiled result is as follows, and as you see, the section title without the number is aligned left to the section title with the number in the second picture.

[image]

But what I used is a local way that I have to add `\hspace{2.3em}` everytime when I want to add section titles without numbers into contents, **so is there a global way to get the desired result as in the second picture as above?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the way, one can also use `\string\numberline{}` instead of `\hspace(2.3em}`.

The `section` argument in `\addcontentsline` is used to select `\l@section` to format the TOC for this entry. Similarly, **one can define a `\l@newsection` to setting the indent of section titles without numbers in the preamble, and then use the codes `\addcontentsline{toc}{newsection}{}`**. Clearly it's a global way.

Alternatively one could redefine `\thesection` temporarily and just use `\section`.  OTOH, this would also increment the section counter.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\makeatletter
\newcommand*\l@newsection[2]{\@dottedtocline{1}{1.5em}{2.3em}{\numberline{}#1}{#2}}
\newcommand*{\toclevel@newsection}{1}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Chapter title}
\section{Section title with numbers}

\phantomsection
\section*{Section title without numbers}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\string\numberline{}Section title without numbers}
\addcontentsline{toc}{newsection}{Section title without numbers}

\renewcommand{\thesection}{}
\section{Section title without numbers}
\addtocounter{section}{-1}%
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\thechapter.\arabic{section}}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! I improve the answer.

Comment: `\addcontentsline{toc}{newsection}{Section title without numbers}` produced another problem: the newsection titles become the same level as the chapter titles in the **bookmark**. Then how to solve it?

Comment: There is no bookmark (whatever that is) in the MWE.

Comment: I used both `tocloft` and `hyperref`, and the `\l@newsection` and `\addcontentsline{toc}{newsection}{Section title without numbers}` codes which produces the section titles with a chapter level in the bookmark.

Comment: I mean in the **bookmark** produced by `hyperref`,  but not in the **contents**.

Comment: So that's what its called.  It seems to be created by `\addcontentsline`, not `\phantomsection` or `\section*`.

Comment: If you check the warnings, you should see something about the toc level for newsection being undefined and defaulting to 0.  Hyperref tries to use  `\toclevel@newsection` for the bookmarks.

Comment: `\newcommand*{\toclevel@newsection}{1}` sovled the problem. Thanks!